# Connecting to MySQL database asynchronously

Tags: c#, mysql, asynchronous, win-universal-app

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database from a UWP app. But it tells me that ExecuteReaderAsync() method is not there. What am I doing wrong here? If this is not possible how can I do a database call asynchronously?

```
public async Task<List<Zone>> GetAllZonesAsync()
        {
            MySqlConnect connect = new MySqlConnect();
            connect.Initialize();
            string query = "SELECT * FROM zones WHERE ACTIVE = true";
            List<Zone> availableZones = new List<Zone>();
            if (connect.OpenConnection())
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connect.Connection);
                MySqlDataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Zone zone = new Zone(reader["ID"].ToString(), reader["ZONENAME"].ToString());
                    availableZones.Add(zone);
                }
            }
            connect.CloseConnection();
            return availableZones;
        }
```

This is my code..

Comment: What provider version are you using? If the provider doesn't have asynchronous methods, that's it. You'll have to find one that does. An alternative is to use BegenExecuteReader, EndExecuteReader and wrap them in a Task with [Task.FromAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The *second* answer in the duplicate question contains an example of using Task.FromAsync with Begin/EndExecuteReader